# What do Influences the Gender Assignment of Words: History, Culture, or Originators?

Tags: gender

In Portuguese, the word for "circle" is "círculo," which is masculine. However, in French, the term "cercle" (meaning "circle") is feminine. Similarly, in German, "Kreis" (also translating to "circle") is feminine.

What factors determine the gender assignment to abstract words like "circle" in different languages?

Comment: It’s masculine in French https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/cercle

Comment: @AlexB. here it says that is feminine: https://www.dictionary-english-french.com/en/dictionary-english-french/circle chatgpt and bard also say its feminine.

Comment: @Humberto No, that link also clearly says it’s masculine. As do Wiktionary, Larousse, CNRTL and every other French dictionary.

Comment: I'd even go as far as to say that in most (if not all?) Romance languages it's masculine: Italian cerchio (m.n.), French cercle (n.m.), Spanish círculo (m.), Romanian cerc (n.), etc. - cf. Latin circulus (m.)

Comment: German *der Kreis* is masculine, and the loan word *der Zirkel* (with different meanings, from a tool to draw circles to a round of people) is masculine, too.

Comment: The question itself is interesting though!

Comment: @janus-bahs-jacquet, ack!, nevertheless, my question remains,perhaps with some other example.

Comment: Why the downvotes? (Yes, there is an error in the question, but the question is clear nonetheless)

Comment: Because the errors stand uncorrected. I'm ready to retract any downvote when a question is improved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

History is by far the most important factor. Portuguese *círculo*, French *cercle*, and so on are masculine because Latin *circulus* was masculine, because Latin *circus* was masculine, because Greek *kírkos* was masculine. As far back as we can trace that word, it's inherited masculinity from its ancestors.

To put it differently, the gender of a word tends to become fixed when the word is adopted (based on analogy with similar-looking words, or some property of its meaning, or just arbitrary convention) and rarely changes after that.

Comment: One exception to the general stability of gender that springs to mind is the Scandinavian words for ‘bee’: Proto-Germanic _*bijō-_ was feminine (as all its gendered descendants outside North Germanic still are); in Old Norse, it became neuter under the influence of _mý_ ‘midge’ (and gained a more common spelling _bý_, still found in Icelandic and Faroese but lost again elsewhere); Swedish _bi_ is still neuter, while Danish _bi_ is commune and Norwegian _bie_ can be either masculine or feminine. So it’s essentially gone feminine → neuter [analogy] → all available genders.

Comment: Another name that changes gender according to the language is *il fiore* in Italian (the flower) which is masculine and *la fleur* in French, which is feminine, despite the fact that both come from the Latin *flos*, masculine.

Comment: @Draconis: Why were Latin 'circulus' and Greek 'kírkos' chosen to be masculine?

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi _Circulus_ is masculine because _circus_ is. _Kírkos_ is masculine for reasons lost to history.

Comment: @Draconis and why is circus masculinre? also lost in history?

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi _Circus_ is masculine because it's borrowed from _kírkos_ which is masculine.

Comment: @Draconis, now I am very very curious about the reasons why kirkos is masculine ...

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi What I'm trying to illustrate with this answer is that, for most words, the answer of "why does it have this gender" is "because its ancestor has this gender", back and back and back until we don't know what the ancestor was.

Comment: @Draconis, I get it! thanks!

Comment: An interesting exception is the name of trees and fruit in Italian: Latin had a very regular pattern (the fruit was second declension neuter, the tree was second declension feminine). The fact that almost all second declension nouns turned masculine in Italian forced a reassignment and the fruit became feminine, while the tree became masculine, by reanalyzing the neuter plural as a feminine singular (so, e.g. from *malum, malus* we got *melo, mela*)